# Pytorcd Resize/input shape

Tags: pytorch

I have a question about the input shape of VGG16 and Resnet50. Both of them have a default input shape of `224` which is a multiple of `32`. Which means I can use my `320 x 256` (height x width) or `320 x 224` (height x width) images. Am I correct?

If I really want to/have to resize my image of `320 x 256` into `244 x 244`, I know I can use the `transforme.resize` function. However, I heard It's not a good way of resizing the image directly like this... In order to prevent this, we use center crop. However, how do we figure out what is the best value for the center crop?